Manipulating JsonPatchDocument -> identifiers to id
We are implementing patch in .net 7, using JsonPatchDocument and want to add a product to a task. Problem is we are not using database id's in the frontend, but identifiers.
Without identifiers, we can currently create a product using the following:
Our operation on the JsonPatchDocument is:
op: "add",
path: "/products",
value: [{ taskId: 1002, productId: 2, companyId: 2, count: 30 }],

And it's done with line:
request.Request.JsonDocument.ApplyTo(task, request.Controller.ModelState);

Now if it was real data coming from the client, our operation on the JsonPatchDocument would be something like: (It does not know db ids on objects)
op: "add",
path: "/products",
value: [{ taskId: 0, productId: 0, companyId: 0, count: 30 }],

and then we would have to send the taskIdentifier: "802D5980-4D33-4091-89E3-DD6FCB57C1B1" seperatly.
We would then have to manipulate the operation for adding products to get the real id's for task, product, company and change the value to the 1# operation example.
How is this manipulating of the json data done in the best way to still be somewhat dynamic?
Note, It's only lists belonging to the task that we have a issue with, because if we wanted to edit a title on a task, we could retrive the task based on the seperate taskIdentifier and give the task object to the ApplyTo. No need for manupulating the data.

'(It does not know db ids on objects)' it is weird to use a patch when you don't know the id. It looks like you are performing a 'CREATE' action but with a 'PATCH' operation.
Consider using a tool for create action or review your design so the id is known prior to a patch operation.

I agree with Greg, this looks more like a CREATE/UPSERT
